# List extending strange behaviour

Tags: python, list

Found interesting thing in Python (2.7) that never mentioned before.

This:

```
a = []
a += "a"
```

does work and result is:

```
>>> a
>>> ["a"]
```

But

```
a = []
a = a + "a"
```

gives

```
>>> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Can someone explain why? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `+` and `+=` are different operations even if they seem to do the same in many situations.

Comment: `+=` behaves like extend() in  python lists(inplace add) and the other one is called binary add.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python distinguishes between the `+` and `+=` operators and provides separate hooks for these; [`__add__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`__iadd__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__). The `list()` type simply provides a different implementation for the latter.

It is more efficient for lists to implement these separately; `__add__` has to return a completely new list, while `__iadd__` can just extend `self` then return `self`.

In the C code, `__iadd__` is implemented by [`list_inplace_concat()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0935ef48186/Objects/listobject.c#l914), which simply calls `listextend()`, or, in python code, `[].extend()`. The latter takes *any* sequence, by design.

The `__add__` method on the other hand, represented in C by [`list_concat`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b0935ef48186/Objects/listobject.c#l506), only takes a `list` as input, probably for efficiency's sake; it can loop directly over the internal C array and copy items over to the new list.

In conclusion, the reason `__iadd__` accepts any sequence is because when [PEP 203](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) (the Augmented Add proposal) was implemented, for lists it was simplest just to reuse the `.extend()` method.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

**If `a` is a list, `a + x` only works if `x` is also list, whereas `a += x` works for any iterable `x`.**

The following might help understand it:

```
In [4]: a = []

In [5]: a += "abc"

In [6]: a
Out[6]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The key is that `"a"` and `"abc"` are iterable, which is what enables their use on the right-hand side of `+=`.

This doesn't work for `+` because the latter requires both operands to be of the same type (see the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)).

To write the same thing using `+`, you have to expand the iterable:

```
In [7]: a = []

In [8]: a = a + list("abc")

In [9]: a
Out[9]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In other words, `+=` is more general than `+` when applied to lists.

Comment: The question is about the *difference* between `lst += iterable` and `lst + iterable`.

Comment: It does not explain why you cannot concatenate a list and an iterable though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure. See the latest answer.