# Adding a tuple element in a list

Tags: python

`<class 'list'>`'s  `insert` method helps to add element `((1,2), (3, 4))` in a `lst` with expected output `lst = [((1,2), (3, 4))]`,

```
lst = []
lst.insert(0, ((1,2), (3, 4)))
lst.insert(1, ((5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

But `+=` operator does not give same result(`lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]`).

```
lst = []
lst += ((1,2), (3, 4))
```

`+=` operator internally calls `__iadd__` method.

Why `__iadd__` does not add element in a way `class <'list'>`'s  `insert(index,element)` method does ? Because maintaining index needs extra name-value pair in my merge sort code is a big overhead..

Comment: @SimeonVisser there is no fight between `+=` and `+` as shown in your old question. `+=` does not change the reference of `lst`, but how no change in reference has anything to do with adding element `((1,2), (3, 4))`

Comment: @vaultah your old question recommends to use `extend` method. DO you think this is my question?

Comment: Duplicate of [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20691982/2301450), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7721192/2301450), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15376509/2301450), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13904039/2301450) and more

Comment: The list `+=` operator doesn't add individual values but values from iterables. You can try `lst += [((1,2), (3, 4))]`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`x += y`, where `x` and `y` are list-like will create a new list with the contents of `y` concatenated to the contents of `x`.

Since you don't want to append the *contents* of the tuple `((1,2), (3, 4))` to `lst`, instead want the *tuple* added to the list, you should `lst.append(((1,2), (3, 4)))` instead.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(((1, 2), (3, 4)))
>>> lst.append(((5, 6), (7, 8)))
>>> lst
[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8))]
```